# Cluster markers in Flutter's flutter_google_map_view widget

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dart, flutter, widget

I searched in [flutter_google_map_view](https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_google_map_view) repository and there is a class called [cluster](https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_google_map_view/blob/master/lib/cluster.dart).

However, there is not an implementation example and this small class seems like only a wrapper for marker class.

What I would like to know is if we should implement clustering according to the tons of examples of iOS/Android native sources? Or does this widget library need to implement clustering in the future? I opened up an Issue in the gitHub page if anybody is interested.

Also, if anybody is kind enough to show a path for implementing this would make a great favor.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The repository that you have shared above was a third party repository and as it states in the `README`, it's not under development anymore. So In favor of the official plugin, it will not be further developed.**

Official maps plugin is called [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter). It has two samples in the official Flutter page on GitHub that you can find [here](https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/master/place_tracker) and [here.](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/example) However, this plugin is not still in 1.0 and it is most likely that the plugin will evolve more and more (*you can check [this tweet](https://twitter.com/flutter_wm/status/1074688156216131585) as a reference*).

So as a roadmap, I would suggest, learn and try to implement the map according to your needs by following along the examples. If you see a missing feature create the issue in the correct place and I am sure someone will get back to you about it.

*I hope this helps, for further questions, just comment below.*